# How would I change the domain of a Taylor polynomial?

Tags: limits, polynomials, power-series, taylor-expansion

Lets say I have a function $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ and I graph its Taylor polynomials from the first order to the $n^{th}$ order. I would find that the Taylor polynomial always has a finite domain for which it is tracing the function. In this case it is always $-1\le x\le 1$.

Is there any way the domain of a Taylor polynomial can be changed? for example, if instead I want the Taylor polynomials of the function $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ to trace the function over the domain $-2\le x\le 2$ instead of tracing $-1\le x\le 1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For that specific function, the Taylor series about the point $a$ has a radius of convergence $\sqrt{a^2 + 1}$. Consequently, you cannot expect any Taylor polynomial to be a good approximation outside the interval $[a - \sqrt{a^2 + 1}, a + \sqrt{a^2 + 1}]$.

The explanation of the radius of convergence comes from complex analysis; the function has the obvious extension to the complex plane, and it has poles at $x = \pm \mathbf{i}$, so general theorems about the radius of convergence tell us that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series about some complex point $a$ is precisely the minimum distance between $a$ and one of the two poles.

---

If you want a polynomial that estimates that function on the interval $[-2, 2]$, Taylor polynomials won't work; you'll have to use some other method of constructing approximating polynomials.

Comment: I heard that the Taylor series could be of use, specifically with this sort of question. But I am not too sure, so just needed clarification.